# Matlab bar plot legend

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, legend

I am try to plot some data into a bar plot and add legend. 
Matlab assigns four colors to the bars, and I am going to add legend to these colors.

My code is:

```
data = rand(8, 4);
l = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
graph = bar(data); 
legend( l );
```

Matlab can plot the graph, but it cannot add legend. 
The error message is:

```
"Error using subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.
Error in plotDisAndStep
legend( l );"
```

Comment: I get the error when I have a variable `legend` and then try to use the function.  Rename the variable and all should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is most probably (as commented TroyHaskin) that you have used `legend` as variable name earlier in your code. Try to put a `clear legend` directly above the line with `legend( l );`. This could be illustrated by this short example

```
l = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
A = 1;
A(l)
 Error: Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.
```

Matlab cannot figure out how to convert the cell `l` to a index.

---

The `legend` command works with ***both*** [comma separeted list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) and a `cell` as input with the different labels.

But, using a *cell* is usually even better as in enables additional [name-value pair input arguments](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html#namevaluepairarguments) without issuing a warning.

> Warning: Ignoring extra legend entries.

For example, with your list of labels `l` (provided that `legend` isn´t overwritten)

```
l = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
```

You could simply use both

```
legend(l)    % Cell input
legend(l{:}) % Cell elements fed separately
```

But using the first you could also add, for example

```
legend(l, 'FontSize', 8)
```

Matlab then understand that labels in `l` are grouped together and the `'FontSize'` isn't a label.

If you use

```
legend(l{:}, 'FontSize', 8);
```

you will get a warning that the number of lines in the plot (4) don't match the number of legend inputs (since 'FontSize' is also assumed to be a label)

Therefore, you will also be in trouble if your `l` list is too short and you provide it as an comma separeted list. Then *FontSize* is included in your legend, see picture below.

```
data = rand(8, 5);  %  <--   Added one extra line
l = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
graph = bar(data); 
legend( l{:}, 'FontSize', 8);
```

[image: Example with bad legend labels]

Note that *FontSize* only is an example of the different name-value pair argument you could use.

Answer (score -1):

You have a [comma separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), so you need to use the following.

```
legend(l{:});
```

The problem you are facing can be because of Matlab version you are using. Otherwise your code also should run. For example, your code is working fine in my version (2016) of Matlab.

Comment: why downvote? please give comments if you think something is wrong!